# How to update one value in a dataframe with a dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, dictionary

I do not manage to update single values in a dataframe based on values of a dictionary before another calculation is executed

I am working with a dataframe and want to calculate values in different colums row per row. After the calculations of one row is finished, the values in the rows thereafter need to be changed before a new calculation can happen. This is since the values in the rows thereafter are dependent upon the results of the previous row.

To approach it, I am working with a dictionary. Currently I am working in Excel where I manage to update the values of a single cell with a dictionary. However to make the calculaton faster I want to work with a proper dataframe.

I manage to update the dictionary based on the results, but I do not manage to update my dataframe with these new values of the citionary

The code that works for my current model based on Excel is:

```
dict1={1:10,2:15.....38:29}     #my dictionary

for row in range(2,sheet.max_row+1):
  #updates the table with values of the dictionary before each calculation
    sheet['F'+str(row)].value = dict1[sheet['C'+str(row)].value] 
  # calculations being executed
        (.....)
  #updating the dictionary with the results of the calculations in the row
    dict1_1={sheet['C'+str(row)].value :sheet['F'+str(row)].value}
    dict1.update(dict1_1)
```

What I tried so far with a dataframe looks like this:

```
 for row in df.T.itertuples():
    df.replace({"P_building_kg_y": dict1}) ##### <-----HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
  # calculations being executed
        (.....)
  #updating the dictionary with the results of the calculations in the row
    dict1_1=dict(zip(df.FacilityID, df.P_building_kg_y))
    dict1.update(dict1_1)
```

I only want to update the values in the dataframe based on the dictionary. If you know a way of how to do it I would really appreciate it!

Comment: according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) `df.replace()`: Replace values given in to_replace with value, so I think you need to pass `list(dict1.values())` or and not just `dict1`.